# How do I map a contingency table to another, by applying a function to each element, in R?

Tags: r, matrix, transformation

I have a 2D contingency table in **R**; it is a table object. I want to transform it into a new table by applying a function on each of its elements.
I looked at sapply, tapply, etc., but they are all aimed at summarising/aggregating the data. I've written my own mapping function which does this, which I reproduce below:

```
map.table = function(t,fn)
{
    rows = dim(t)[1]
    columns = dim(t)[2]
    x = matrix(nrow=rows, ncol=columns)

    rownames(x) = unlist(dimnames(bush.t)[1], use.names=FALSE)
    colnames(x) = unlist(dimnames(bush.t)[2], use.names=FALSE)
    for(row in seq(from=1, to=rows))
    {
        for(column in seq(from=1, to=columns))
        {
            x[row,column] = fn(t[row,column])
        }
    }
    as.table(x)
}
```

This creates a matrix from scratch, fills up the dimension names, and the elements. Is there a better way of doing this? Is there an **R** function/package which already does this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably just use `apply`:

```
set.seed(21)
x <- data.frame(a=sample(letters[1:5],20,TRUE),
                b=sample(letters[1:5],20,TRUE))
y <- table(x)
z <- as.table(apply(y, 1:2, sqrt))
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you going to all this trouble? You should be able to do this:

```
fn(t)
```

(But also consider using a different name for your table, since `t` is a perfectly good base function name. At first I thought you were transposing your rows and columns.)

If your function does not work with vectors there is the possibility you can persuade it to do so. Try this:

```
vfn <- Vectorize(fn)
t2[] <- vfn(t)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but it returned only a single number with warning messages to the effect "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

Comment: I think this is because the function I am trying to apply has if-else conditions to determine the value of an element. Unconditional transformations work just fine.

Comment: You error message suggests you are using if() but giving it an entire vector. There are probably better ways to design a function so that it can be properly applied to vectors.